# TypeLoadException for Dictionary Mock error in xUnit

Tags: c#, dictionary, .net-core, moq, xunit

I am working on .NET xUnit. I have created Mock for Dictionary<string, StringValues>() but getting System.TypeLoadException error.

I have notice the issue is in CreateMockHttpRequest method (refer in code) in the following line

```
request.Query = new QueryCollection(query);
```

`xUnit`

```
[Fact]
    public void MyTestA()
    {
        //Arrange
        var queryVal = new Dictionary<string, StringValues>();
        queryVal.TryAdd("sessions", providerSession.ProviderSessionId);

        Mock<HttpRequest> mockHttpRequest = httpResquestFactory.CreateMockHttpRequest(queryVal);
     }
```

`Mock Http Method`

```
public class HttpResquestFactory
{
  public Mock<HttpRequest> CreateMockHttpRequest(Dictionary<string, StringValues> query)
    {
        var context = new DefaultHttpContext();

        var request = context.Request;

        request.Query = new QueryCollection(query);

        var mockRequest = new Mock<HttpRequest>();

        mockRequest.Setup(x => x.Query).Returns(request.Query);

        return mockRequest;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Check to make sure you have the correct reference. The namespace shown in the exception had me wondering if you are referencing the correct library. Check the namespace used in the source code here https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http/QueryCollection.cs

Comment: I am using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal; Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;

Comment: One of these need to be closed as a duplicate of the [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70378218/init-private-property-with-nsubstitute-and-then-test-it-as-regular-property) since they both appear to be addressing the same problem. Which one would you prefer to remain open?.

Comment: Why do you even need the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal;` namespace?

Comment: I am require this for QueryCollection , code not recognizing QueryCollection if I am missing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal

Comment: then I believe you are referencing the wrong version of that library